# Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, menu, web

I have this code

```
jQuery(function($) {
    'use strict';

    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
        Scroll();
    });

    $('.navbar-collapse ul li a').on('click', function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - 5 
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    });

    function Scroll() {
        var contentTop = [];
        var contentBottom = [];
        var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var rangeTop = 200;
        var rangeBottom = 500;
        $('.navbar-collapse').find('.scroll a').each(function() {
            contentTop.push($($(this).attr('href')).offset().top);
            contentBottom.push($($(this).attr('href')).offset().top + $($(this).attr('href')).height());
        })
        $.each(contentTop, function(i) {
            if (winTop > contentTop[i] - rangeTop) {
                $('.navbar-collapse li.scroll')
                    .removeClass('active')
                    .eq(i).addClass('active');
            }
        })
    };
```

I tried keep getting this error when loading the code: 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined.
The effected lines are 9 and 21

Just in case this helps, the site this code is loading on works fine as it's html file, but doesn't when its set up as a WHMCS theme
The HTML this should be working with is

```
<nav id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="templates/six/images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="scroll active"><a href="#home" class="active">Home</a></li> 
            <li class="scroll"><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
                        <li class="scroll"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                        <li class="scroll"><a href="#domains">Domains</a></li> 
                        <li class="scroll"><a href="#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
                                                <li class="scroll"><a href="#clientarea">Client Area</a></li>
                                                <li class="scroll"><a href="#contact-us">Support</a></li>                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div><!--/.container-->
        </nav>
```

Comment: Add HTML code also in the question

Comment: Show HTML and which line in the JS is the error referring to?

Comment: do you know what template this is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

`$($(this).attr('href')).offset().top`

You are sending the result of getting the href into the Jquery `$`function which will return an object with an undefined `offset()` as it's not part of the page.

`$('my-a-tag').offset().top` where `my-a-tag` finds your a tag uniquely will work, as long as `my-a-tag` exists on the page.

This [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/118hw2rd/8/) demonstrates. Open the console to see the difference between the object returned by your code and the object returned by the correct code. Also, see the `offset()` function working correctly.

Here's also an example line that should work in your code:

`contentTop.push($(this).offset().top);`

In this this case we just use `this` rather than a class like in the jsfiddle as we're in a loop which is going through all the anchors.

Comment: There's a lot. Is there any way that I could give you the website URL and you could use inspect element to take a look?

Comment: if you like ... I'll have a quick look

Comment: Ok, the URL is http://hostinnovative.com The issue is with the navbar, it wont scroll according to the active section, and home doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: @David2100 according to the inspector the code hasn't been changed, you'll need to add my code to stop the error!

Comment: I mean yeah I guess, but it broke the code under it.

Comment: @David2100 that probably means you have to fix the code under it ... the jsfiddle proves that the error in the question is caused by the line I point out, so that's not going to go away unless you change it - a new error means a new debugging effort and possibly a new question